# Postgres array handling in Doctrine 2, Symfony 2.2

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use an integer array data type in a postgres DB, using Doctrine 2 as the ORM. Initially, I was creating the form field as an entity type in Symfony and assumed the entities were the source of this error:

`request.CRITICAL: Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO actions (bundle_key, name, type, num_installs, countries, enabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["05e4a7e5", "sfsdfdsfs", "1", "3", "O:43:\"Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\":1:{s:54:\"\u0000Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\u0000_elements\";a:3:{i:0;O:39:\"... truncated for SO question ...Bundle\\Entity\\Country\u0000latitude\";s:5:\"18.25\";s:50:\"\u0000AirInstaller\\AdminBundle\\Entity\\Country\u0000longitude\";s:8:\"-63.1667\";}}}", "true"]:`

`SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information (uncaught exception) at /Users/steveadams/Sites/airinstaller/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php line 47 [] []`

Upon looking at the crazy serialization going on, I decided to try storing the countries as their ids by building a choice field, making it so the field wouldn't be interpreted as an entity. This failed as well. I then decided to inspect the documentation where I discovered array support in doctrine is actually just a serialized string of a php array! This doesn't work at all if my column type is actually array in the DB.

So my conundrum is this: Do I create a custom mapping type which stores these countries in the proper format for a postgres integer[]: `{2,13,26,43}`

Or do I ask my database admin to change the column to character and store the serialized arrays Doctrine would like to use? That seems so dirty.

In either case I'm pretty disappointed. I'd like to think I'm doing something wrong since the bottom line here is that Doctrine is not supporting an integer[] out of the box. Is that really the case?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: This is not a normal 'doctrine' thing to do.  Typically, you'd make a country entity, and then use foreign keys to keep it associated.  Likely, you'd be using many-to-many relations for what it seems you're doing above.    The array approach is somewhat like a flattened database.  If reworking your datamodel is out of the question, you can construct the query by building strings up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I decided to do.

Since I was discarding relations and opting to store flat arrays of ids for countries, my choice was simply writing a custom mapping type which does basic assertions about data types and writes a postgres-friendly array of ids in string format. I do some sanitation to ensure the ids reference real countries in the database, so that job is no longer completed by Doctrine unfortunately. On the bright side, it's a simple process that works seamlessly with the new database.

The mapping type recurses for multidimensional arrays, so it's suitable for fairly complex data. Unfortunately, this data can't be based on a Doctrine Model, thus utilizing the benefits of that framework. It seems to be a matter of trade offs. In all of my research, it appeared essentially impossible to easily integrate Doctrine with some of postgres' data types.